# How to format the number string in HTML with thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

How can I format the number string as 4digit format using thymeleaf.
Eg. 5 - > 0005

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Format the string using number format. As follow :

```
th:text="${#numbers.formatInteger(num,5)}"
```

Comment: There's a missing closing bracket I could not edit because it's a small change

Comment: Link to the doc: https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.6.RELEASE/index.html?org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using thymeleaf 3.0.9, referring to the [Thymeleaf format](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects).
You can do this in two  ways,

```
 <p th:text="${#numbers.formatInteger(AccountNo,10)}"> This text will replace by AccountNo</p>
```

and

```
<p >Hi format [[${#numbers.formatInteger(AccountNo,10)}]] </p>
```

10 is the maximum length of an account number.

***If you provide 8 digit number then this will add two leading zero*** and if length exceed max size then there will no change in output i.e same as input.

eg. `input: 12345678` then `output: 0012345678`